# NFS Most Wanted Stopped Working On Ronnie Rival Challenge

Tags: need-for-speed-most-wanted-2005

My game was working all fine so far. I am on to rival challenge for Black List #3 'Ronnie'. Game stops when i start rival challenge with Ronnie.

I would be great if anyone faced this problem and solved.

I am playing it on: Windows 7 (64 bit)

Answer (score 1):

Update your patch to BE 1.3 and restart your system, then start your nfsMW application in installed folder.
Hope it works!